# update html of a list from input having anchor and image tag also

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I want a jquery code, please check the comment in the script.afetr click here i want code, to add inputText in li and rest the same
i don't know why posting a question is so creepy first time?

```
<body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="main">
                <input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Please write your task here....">
                <button>Click To Add</button>
            </div>

            <div class="data">enter code here
                <ul>
                    <li>Item aided shown here <a id="del-button" href="https://www.google.com">
                            <img src="del.png" alt="delete-button"> </a> </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            </ class="content">

    <script>
    $('document').ready(function () {

         var cont = $('.content');

         $('button').click(function () {
              var inputText = $('input');
              var newList = $('li').first().clone();

              // now afetr click here i want code, to add inputText in li and rest the same


         })

    })

    </script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('button').click(function () {
    var inputText = $('input').val();
    var newList = $('<li></li>');
    newList.append(inputText);
    newList.append('<a id="del-button" href="https://www.google.com"><img src="del.png" alt="delete-button"> </a>');
    $("ul").append(newList);
 });
```

Also note that your HTML code is broken, before your `<script>` tag you have `</ class="content">` instead of `</div class="content">`.

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j14v7aps/1/).

Comment: Note that I have updated my code because it had an issue. It should be $("ul").append(newList); instead of $("li").append(newList);

Comment: If this answered your question, you can accept this answer so your question will be marked as closed/solved. As you mentioned it's your first question and therefore maybe don't know how this works and why, just check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235